# How do I reference one of the text boxes in this survey to be able to automate typing into them?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, bots

---

```
  import time
  from selenium import webdriver

  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver_win32 
  (1)\chromedriver.exe')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.

  driver.get('https://survey.zohopublic.com/zs/K8CNBt');
  firstName = driver.find_element_by_class_name('inTextBox')
  firstName.send_keys('This is my name')
  # firstName.submit()
  time.sleep(5)  # pause for a bit
  driver.quit()
```

---

So i making a bot to auto fill this form to get more entries. I just cant figure out what to use to be able to reference the text box. There is no set name or ID that I can reference it with. I cant find something on selenium to call for this text box. Helppp?

The link to the website so you can see the code is: https://survey.zohopublic.com/zs/K8CNBt

Answer (score 0):

You can access them using this xpath `(//input[@class=' inTextbox'])[text_box_number]`. Replace `text_box_number` with number `1` to `7` to access text boxes `First Name`
 till `Email`

Comment: firstName = driver.find_element_by_xpath(//input[@class =' inTextbox'])[1]
firstName.send_keys('This is my first name')
time.sleep(5)

Comment: Am i doing something wrong? I keep getting syntax errors

Comment: I figured it out! I'm just a little slow. Thank you for the help!